# Запятая перед "чего"

Tags: запятые

Ставится ли запятая перед словом "чего" так же (в тех же случаях), как и со словом "что"? К примеру: «Но каждый раз, когда он вспоминал(,) чего уже достиг, это прибавляло ему сил идти дальше». В данном случае нужна запятая перед "чего"? Если произносить предложение вслух, то перед этим словом у меня явная пауза.

Comment: Если в ответе есть полезная информация - можете нажать на верхний серый треугольник (возле ответа). Если ответ решил проблему - можете поставить зелёную галочку (она может быть только у одного ответа). А именно таким образом: http://i.imgur.com/jnvr8HZ.png При этом отвечающие понимают, что не зря старались и что их ответ помог. Тогда больше людей будет вам отвечать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, в этом случае не важно, *"что"* здесь или *"чего",* и логика та же. Тут придаточное в придаточном. Запятая нужна.